# Flutter Web Animation Controller Gets in Indeterminate State When Website is Minimized or in Background

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, animationcontroller

In Flutter Web I run into an issue with the animation controller.

See the sample flutter codelessly website here: https://gallery.codelessly.com/flutterwebsites/flutterwebsite/#/. To reproduce the issue, open this website on a mobile browser, and then leave the browser running in the background for a while. When you tab back, you should see the website built but the animation window empty.
See this code repo here: https://github.com/Codelessly/FlutterWebsite

The animation controller seems to throw a stackoverflow exception in this state, something like this:

```
main.dart.js:19150 Stack Overflow
main.dart.js:19150     at qm.kC (https://website/main.dart.js:26388:10)
main.dart.js:19150     at qm.v (https://website/main.dart.js:26389:20)
main.dart.js:19150     at ahr.$1 (https://website/main.dart.js:36324:18)
main.dart.js:19150     at Kg.t (https://website/main.dart.js:26658:30)
main.dart.js:19150     at KK.t (https://website/main.dart.js:26626:34)
main.dart.js:19150     at oe.aI (https://website/main.dart.js:29992:7)
main.dart.js:19150     at Object.axU (https://website/main.dart.js:20110:25)
main.dart.js:19150     at Object.aAa (https://website/main.dart.js:7917:250)
main.dart.js:19150     at Object.aGB (https://website/main.dart.js:7950:21)
main.dart.js:19150     at Object.aoj (https://website/main.dart.js:7914:20)
```

What is causing this exception? How might I avoid this and rebuilt/restart the animation controller in this state?